# The type name 'GetName' does not exist in the type 'MyCountry'

Tags: c#, .net

I create a new Class Library.

Add a new resx file called MyCountry.resx and add some resources to it.

Two entries of Name and Value. I set the Access Modifier to Public so i can reference this class and use it in other projects.

I create another new Class Library and reference the above CL and all seems to work well when i write the below code:

```
var someValue = ClassLibrary.MyCountry.GetName;
```

I then decide to change an Attribute of the same class declaration to use the same Resource entry. Example of working Attribute (shortened for clarity)

```
[Tree("SomethingHere", "SomethingThere")]
```

This works but when i change it to

```
[Tree(ClassLibrary.MyCountry.GetName, "SomethingThere")]
```

I receive the error

*An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type*.

So change it to

```
[Tree(typeof(ClassLibrary.MyCountry.GetName), "SomethingThere")]
```

but then i receive

*The type name 'GetName' does not exist in the type 'MyCountry'*

When i know it does as it works on the code shown above.

Is it possible to have Attributes to use a value from a resx CL in the manner i have shown, am i missing something or is it not possible?

Comment: "When i know it does as it works on the code shown above." No, it doesn't exist as a type. You've shown that it's a *property* - it's not a *type*.

Comment: But basically, no, attribute values must be compile-time constants. You can't get them from resources or anything else loaded at execution time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the compiler states in warning. It needs a value that is known at compile time, but the values for `.resx` files are loaded at Runtime.

You can look this up in the `MyCountry.Designer.cs` that is created automatically along the `MyCountry.resx` file.

There are 2 Solutions for your Problem that come to my mind:

1. You create a `class` that contains all all the constants.

```
public class MyCountry
{
    public const string GetName = "Lorem Ipsum";
}
```

2. You create/use an [Source Generator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/source-generators-overview) that creats such a class from the `.resx` so that the compiler can access it at compile-time.